# Webhook for Firestore - Flutter Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a chat system **(with Firebase & Flutter)** where i listen to streams of collections for **incoming message**. Right now, i am listening to **10 streams** at once which means i am listening for 10 Chat rooms for any incoming message.

**QUESTION :** Are there **webhooks** available for Firestore so we can trigger/notify that there is a certain change in any collection and start listening to the stream of that collection?

The idea is to listen to only those **collections/ChatRooms** which are receiving new data. I have researched on this but found no possible solution yet.

Comment: "I listen to streams of collections for incoming message" => Which exact method are you using? The [`snapshots()`](snapshots() method which returns a Stream:) method(s) which return a Stream?

Comment: Yes, i am using stream builder to listen for any change in collection and receiving new data with snapshots.

Comment: This is the standard way to listen to new docs (as well as modified and deleted) in a collection. In other words, the answer to "Are there webhooks available for Firestore so we can trigger/notify that there is a certain change in any collection" is to use `snapshots()`! You would need to build your own mechanism if you want something different (managing less streams if I understand correctly). For example having a Cloud Function that creates a flag document in a specific collection that you listen to. When a flag is created you start listening the collection that triggered the Cloud Function.

Comment: You are absolutely right about this. Mechanism should be like if, let's say, there are 15 people/chatrooms which user is connected to. Firstly, we can listen to 10 chatrooms for any incoming messages. Secondly, and here is the real problem, if any last 5 chatrooms/collection gets any new data and we are not listening to them, then how are we suppose to receive new data for them. We don't even know that there is new data on that collection. Now, here is that where webhook come in. If, somehow a webhook can be attached to those collections we are not listening to, then webhook can notify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send write a [Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) that listens to your collection and when there is a new message, you send an [FCM data message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#data_messages) containing the collection information to the device. Then, when the device receives the data message, you set up the stream and listen to it.

Comment: Exactly the right answer. I already had worked on that and possibly this is the only solution to this problem. Is there no possibility of webhook for Firestore?